# Retornar un objeto como valor en una función de un servicio

Tags: angular, firebase

Tengo un error a la hora de retornar un objeto en una función de un servicio:

```
======
Error: src/app/servicios/miservicio.service.ts:98:12 - error TS2454: Variable 'obtejoRespuesta' is used before being assigned.

98     return obtejoRespuesta;

======
```

El código del servicio es este:

```javascript
     crearUsuario(email: string, password: string): Respuesta
      {
        
        let obtejoRespuesta: Respuesta;
        
        
        console.log("Vamos a crear un usuario");
        this.angularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(res=>{
          //console.log("Hemos creado el usuario");

          obtejoRespuesta = { 
            valor: true,
            comentario: "Se ha guardado ok"
          };

          console.log("Valor-->" + obtejoRespuesta.valor);
          console.log("Comentario-->" + obtejoRespuesta.comentario);
          
        }).catch(err=>{

          let obtejoRespuesta = {
            valor: true,
            comentario: "No se ha guardado ok"
          };

          console.log("Valor" + obtejoRespuesta.valor);
          console.log("Comentario " + obtejoRespuesta.comentario);          
        });     
        return obtejoRespuesta;
        
      }
```

No entiendo, dónde se supone que debería poner el "return obtejoRespuesta;" para que no me diese error?

Para más información agrego el componente donde se llama a ese servicio:

```javascript
    crearUsuario(email: string, password: string)
      {
        let retorno: Respuesta = this.miservicio.crearUsuario(email, password);

        if(retorno.valor==true)
        {
          console.log("USARIO CREADO");
        }else{
          console.log("USUARIOS NO CREADO " + retorno.comentario);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Eso es porque `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` es una función asíncrona, lo que pasa dentro del `then()` sucede despues del `return obtejoRespuesta` por lo que en realidad deberías devolver la promesa y manejarla en donde la necesites

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` es una función asíncrona, lo que pasa dentro del `then()` se ejecuta después de `return obtejoRespuesta` por lo que en realidad deberías devolver la promesa y manejarla en donde la necesites.

Esto sería:

```javascript
async crearUsuario(email: string, password: string): Respuesta {
 console.log("Vamos a crear un usuario");
        
 let respuesta = await this.angularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(res=>{
        let objetoRespuesta = { 
          valor: true,
          comentario: "Se ha guardado ok"
        };
        return objetoRespuesta;
  }).catch(err=>{
       let objetoRespuesta = {
         valor: false,
         comentario: "No se ha guardado ok"
       };
       return objetoRespuesta;
  });   
  return respuesta;      
}
```

Y en el componente donde se llama a ese servicio:

```javascript
crearUsuario(email: string, password: string) {
 this.miservicio.crearUsuario(email, password)
   .then(retorno => {
      if(retorno.valor==true) { // acá puedes hacer if(retorno.valor) directamente
        console.log("USARIO CREADO");
      } else {
        console.log("USUARIOS NO CREADO " + retorno.comentario);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Una pregunta. Imagina que ahora dentro  del "then"  en vez de hacer un "console.log("USARIO CREADO");" quiero hacer un **return true** o en vez de "console.log("USARIO NO CREADO");" quiero hacer un **return  false** para que la función **crearUsuario(email: string, password: string)**devuelva un booleano tal cual, no quiero q devuelva una promesa.

Comment: Para eso tendrias que poner `async` en la funcion `crearUsuario(email: string, password: string)` y usar un `await` en la linea  `this.miservicio.crearUsuario(email, password)`. Te recomiendo que leas esta respuesta en donde explican lo que quieres hacer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33579720/8179980

Comment: Si yo pongo un **return false;** al fina lde una función que lleva **async** , ¿realmente mes está recornado un booleano?¿O me está renornando una promesa que devuelve un booleano?...no lo entiendo muy bien

Comment: Exacto, si la funcion lleva `async` entonces devuelve una promesa. Puedes consultar mas sobre esto aquí https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/orphaned/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function